# Can a planar graph have multiple edges joining 2 vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

If they are planar, do the properties $2E \geq 3F$ and $E \leq 3V-6$ remain true?

For example, consider 2 vertices joined by 2 non-intersecting edges. Then $E=2, F=2$ and $V=2$ and $2E \not > 3F$.

Are there any specific rules for these graphs?

Comment: Eulers formula ($N-E+F=2$) still holds, but $E\geq 3F $ assumes each face has at least three edges on its boundary, which obviously isn't true in the example you gave.

Comment: One has to make clear which definition of "graph" is being used. Some definitions disallow [multiple edges (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_edges).

Comment: Once you introduce duals of planar graphs, it becomes hard to avoid loops and multiple edges - think about the dual of a tree.